# Persistent OTP on Web Browser using cookie

Tags: one-time-password

Currently I'm planning to use OTP for my web app, I'm a bit confused about how to keep the users logged on the app. My plan is to use cookies, but I'm not sure whether this is correct or not.

This is my plan for the moment

1. User request for password, server generate public_key, otp, private_key, save the private_key, hash (combination of public_key, otp, and private_key) on the database and save the public_key in the user's browser using cookie and send the otp to user's phone number via sms
2. User receive the otp and validate it on different page, like "verify" page or something, server will fetch the required data from database based on the public_key from cookie, then compare the retrieved hash with user's input hash (public_key from cookie, inputted otp, retrieved private_key), if it's same then it will set the hash to cookie
3. Every time user visit the web, server will check the saved public_key and hash from cookie then compare it on the database and check if the hash is still valid (expired on 5 minutes or so) then retrieve the user's data

What I'm asking is whether there is a more suitable approach for my use case on otp with it's persistent on web browser or I'm doing it right.

Comment: It is not clear for me what do you want to achieve with this setup. Usually OTP is used to protect the authentication or some specific transaction and not the full session like you are trying to do. This means it is checked only once and if it is as expected the user is logged and stays logged in until logout or session timeout, i.e. the usual session handling which does not involve any OTP at all.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich My app authentication method for login is otp using their phone number as username, I want the user stay logged at my website for 30 minutes or so after they login, but storing the phone number and the otp on cookie whould be bad I think, so the plan above is what come to my mind

Comment: What you need to implement is no different from normal logins, only that the login is not done with a form containing username and password but one containing phone and OTP. After  successful login you issue a session cookie as you would do when logging in with username and password. There is nothing special regarding OTP here.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich So regarding this, would it best for me to change it to phone number and password then implementing otp on specific feature on the web? And thank you for you comment, it gave me some light here.

Comment: *"...would it best for me to change it to phone number and password..."* - I don't understand what you mean by this. OTP is an authentication factor and password is another one. If you require one or both depends on your specific use case. But if you use it as a single factor than the user name is essentially the phone number and the password is the OTP and you handle these similar to other user name and password scenarios.